# Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm having the following timeout error when I put the computer to sleep while a SQL select process was running and bringing it back up online.

> Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:53), database ID 10.

Because it takes time for the computer to unsleep, the process fails and is waiting for something from the SQL Server that just woke up.

Is there a way to set this time out (increase it) in C#, in like `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter` from .NET?

Comment: The problem is not the time to unsleep. SQL Server has no problem with seconds-long IOs. The problem is the hours long sleep itself causing the timeout. (This does not help you. Just an observation.)

Comment: This is an internal error produced by SQL Server because it had to go to sleep in the middle of some work. SQL Server tends to be used in server environments, where suspend/resume isn't even an issue, so I doubt it's been verified to work properly under those conditions (though I could be wrong). The latch time-out is *5 minutes* -- there is no way to increase this internal value, nor would it make sense to make it even longer if 5 minutes isn't enough. If you get this message as an `SqlException`, you'll just have to handle it and redo any work the application was doing (where appropriate).